# Change Display property on button click with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, click

I'm trying to load a page where some divs are hidden, looks something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnStats" values="Stats"/>
<div id="dvStats" style="display:none">Stats</div>
<div id="dvAlbums" style="display:none">Albums</div>
```

Right now divs have just text, since I can't get them to work. 
I have a JS that assigns dvStats display to click event on btnStats.

```
$("#btnStats").click($("#dvStats").style.display="block");
```

Also tried with some methods I saw while searching older questions about this.

```
$("#btnStats").click($("#dvStats").css(":display","block"));
```

I haven't been able to make this work. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: quick question, is the colon a typo, or in the actual code you tried for `:display`?

Answer (score 9):

Using Jquery you can easily do the above task.Include Jquery Library, and use this code:

```
$("#btnStats").on("click",function(){

    $("#dvStats").css("display","block")
    $("#dvAlbums").css("display","block")

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#btnStats").click(function() {
    $("#dvStats").css("display","block");
        /* OR  */
    $("#dvStats").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, rather than using the `.css()` method use the `.show()` method as it does the same thing:

```
$("#btnStats").click(function () {
    $("#dvStats").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) takes a callback function as a parameter, so you need to pass a function as an argument to the click function call.

```
$("#btnStats").click(function(){
    $("#dvStats").show()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P92YK/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your button handler to this for example:

```
$("#btnStats").click(function() {
          $("#dvStats").show();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why:

```
$("#btnStats").click($("#dvStats").css("display","block"));
```

wouldn't work (note the removal of the colon before the word 'display').

P.S. You have got the jQuery library in your file haven't you?

Otherwise you'll need to setup an onclick event which calls a function to do a:

```
document.getElementById('dvStats').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Because if click takes an argument, it has to be a function pointer, which you get either by $('#btnStats').click(func); function func() { /*foobar */}, or by $('#btnStats').click(function(){ /*foobar*/ });

Comment: Yeah, I have the latest Jquery file added. Yet, that code line(with css) launches itself without me even clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnStats").click(function () {
$("#cont div").toggleClass('hidden').removeClass('visible').siblings().toggleClass('visible').addClass('hidden'); // change class to Hidden if Visible
});
<div id="cont">   
<div id="dvStats" class="visible">Stats</div>
<div id="dvAlbums" class="hidden">Albums</div>
</div>
```